# Change Kendo Grids DataSource group programmatically

Tags: jquery, typescript, kendo-grid

How can I change the group programmatically after the Kendo grid has been rendered? I have tried a function like this in my TypeScript:

```
changeGroupBy() {
    var group = $('#ddGroupBy').val();
    var grid = $('#objectsListGrid').data('kendoGrid');
    var options = grid.options;

    options.dataSource = this.objectsList;
    options.dataSource.group = group;
    grid.refresh();
}
```

When I used the above code I get an error that this.group is not a function?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is a better way to do it now. After the grid is rendered just use below

```
$('#objectsListGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.group({field: $('#ddGroupBy').val()});
```

Also for multiple 'Group by' fields if any, use below

```
$('#objectsListGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.group(
 [
  {field: $('#ddGroupBy').val()},
  {field: $('#ddGroupBy2').val()}
 ]
);
```

Here are the details
https://www.telerik.com/forums/grid---dynamically-change-grouping

Answer (score 1):

You should use: dataSource.group({ field: "yourField" });

As explained here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-group

Comment: This is the pre-rendered method which I already know about. I need to be able to change the grouping after the page has been rendered. A user will select a value in a drop down and I want to trigger a grouping based on the field they selected.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can't just set the group property AFTER the grid has been rendered without first getting a reference to the grid and it's options and then destroying the grid and rebuilding it. These are the steps I did and it is working correctly:

```
    var grid = $('#objectsListGrid').data('kendoGrid');

    this.getObjects(this.projectNumber);
    var options = grid.options;


    options.dataSource = this.objectsList;
    options.dataSource.group({ field: group });
    grid.destroy();

    $('#objectsListGrid').empty().kendoGrid(options);
    grid.dataSource.read();
```